# How to transform a list of 1-D ndarray to 2-D ndarray (mxnet ndarray)

Tags: python, numpy, mxnet, numpy-ndarray

In this example, I have a list of 1-d ndarray, with length 9, the list has 9 elements, and each one has `shape=(2048,)`, so totally `9 * (2048,)`, I get these `ndarray` from `mxnet` so that each of the `ndarray` is `<NDArray 2048 @cpu(0)>` the array `dtype=numpy.float32`

If I use `np.asarray` to transform this list, it becomes the following result

`shape=<class 'tuple'>: (9, 2048, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)`

Obviously, I want a 2-D array, with `shape=(9, 2048)`, how to solve this problem?

ps: I discover this problem by saving a `npy` file and load it. I directly saved the list before converting it to a `ndarray` (so the `np.save` would transform the list to the `ndarrary` automatically) and after I loaded it, I found the shape has become something above, which is really abnormal

**The answer below, `np.vstack` and `np.array` both works for the common `list` to `ndarray` problem but could not solve mine, so I doubt it is some special case of `mxnet`**

Comment: All those 1s is suspicious.  The len of the tuple is 32, the maximum number of dimensions.  It's almost like there's some sort of recursive definition or nesting.  It might be instructive to do `[i.shape for in arr]` to check the shape all 9 elements.  Squeeze should be able to remove those 1s, but it would still be nice to know why it produces that shape.  Also what's the `dtype` - object for the original, but what about the elements and the result?

Comment: @hpaulj I checked from the debugger, all the 9 elements are with shape `(2048,)`

Comment: What does `np.array(the_list[0]` produce?  Or `np.array(the_list[0][0])`.  You still haven't told us what the array dtype is.  It must be `object`.  So you have a list (or object array) of 9 object arrays, etc.  Elements of an object array (or list) are  pointers.  `np.save` uses `pickle` to write objects.  It could be that the `pickle` code for the `mxnet` object is screwy, and producing this recursive shape.

Comment: Based on a glance at `mxnet` I think you should use `mxnet.ndarray` functions or methods when saving your list of mxnet ndarrays.  Don't count on `numpy` code to handle this external library correctly; it's isn't aware of the nuances.  Or convert the mxnet arrays with the `asnumpy` method.

Comment: @hpaulj I added the `dtype=numpy.float32` and I test the `np.array(the_list[0])`, it changes the original array! (from `(2048,)` to `(2048, 1, 1, 1,...)`)  so is it a `mxnet` bug?

Comment: Try `the_list[0].asnumpy()`.

Comment: @hpaulj I see, so the point is that `mxnet` array does not fit with `numpy`

Comment: @hpaulj `asnumpy()` works! So this could be the correct answer, please write an answer if you are available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.vstack`. Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np

li = [np.zeros(2048) for _ in range(9)]
result = np.vstack(li)
print(result.shape)
```

This outputs `(9, 2048)` as desired.

Comment: Thanks, this is a solution, but my problem still exists. I tried this code and it did generate a `(9,2048)` array, but when I use `np.vstack` in my code, my original problem remains. Since there is only one line of code, so I think the problem is the original list. My list is `float32` type, and there is a `T` element in each of my `ndarray`, does this matters?

Comment: What's a `T! element?

Comment: Just add, `np.array` give the same result of `np.vstack` in this example

Comment: @hpaulj The `T` element seems to be recursive in the debugger, however, in the above example which gives the correct result, there is also a `T` and `_internals_` and they are also recursive, I use PyCharm and these elements are shown in the debugger

Comment: @hpaulj In my code (in the question), it shows as `result: T={ndarray} {T={ndarray} {..recursive}}` and in this example (code in this answer) it shows as `result: _internal_ {T={ndarray} {_internal_} {..recursive}}`

Comment: @hpaulj By the way I do not think this `T` is relevant to my problem

Comment: I added some detail to the question, please see my update

Comment: I think the `T` is central to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the guy who gives the correct answer as comment solve my problem but did not post an answer, I would post his answer here for the others who may also encounter this problem

In fact, the `np.array` and `mxnet.ndarray` are not exactly the same, so it is dangerous to directly call `numpy` methods on `mxnet.ndarray`. To use `numpy` method in `mxnet.ndarray`, we should first transform the array to `np.array`, which is

```
mx_ndarray = mxnet.ndarray.zeros(5)
np_array = mx_ndarray.asnumpy()
```

Then `numpy` methods could be used on `np_array`

Since the above answer is more general(`np.vstack()`), I accept it and just post this answer as a reference, also, `np.array()` does the same thing in the above example with `np.vstack()`